# ggplot: How can I add a second legend to a plot where factors all have different aesthetics and only 1 factor has a color gradient

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-point

I've coded this scatterplot but am hitting a wall and could use some help. I'd like it to include two legends:
one is intensity for only one of the factors (shown below), which I'm able to do
the other would include the shape for all factors and maybe color - this I'm not able to figure out.

Here is my dataset and code:

```
lvl <-  c("mid","mid","mid","mid","mid","mid","mid","mid","mid","mid","high","high","high","high",            
          "high","high","high","high","high","high","low","low","low","low","low","low","low",
          "low","low","low")
x <- c(6.06,4.42,6.81,1.7,1.29,6.75,4.48,2.64,4.31,3.93,1.56,2.25,6.53,4,5.09,3.7,1.19,7.71,4.4,8.49,
       4.14,5.37,7.1,2.94,1.75,2.49,1.37,1.22,9.29,1.37)
y <- c(4.17,1.41,6.79,1.72,1.45,7.29,4.49,2.72,1.34,6.66,3.94,2.84,7.3,3.97,4.95,9.03,5.23,8.77,1.13,
       2.76,5.3,4.53,7.42,3.15,6.97,2.36,1.07,1.16,9.17,1.72)
z <- c(1.26,1.34,2.53,3.83,2.78,9.93,1.23,9.97,1.71,1.3,1.31,1,6.06,2.26,3.29,2.29,2.52,2.02,2.68,
       9.7,2.9,1.7,6.65,9.54,2.05,1.06,3.59,1.16,2.99,1.14)

data <- data.frame(lvl,x,y,z)
low <- data %>% filter(lvl == "low")
mid <- data %>% filter(lvl == "mid")
high <- data %>% filter(lvl == "high")

ggplot(data = result_df, aes(x=x, y=y, color=lvl, shape=lvl)) +
     geom_point(data = high, color = "gray81", shape = 18, size = 2, aes(color="high")) +
     geom_point(data = mid, shape = 2, size = 4, stroke = 1.5, color = "black",aes(color="mid")) +
     theme_classic()+
     theme(legend.position="right")+
     geom_point(data = low, size = 4, shape = 21, stroke = 1.5, color = "black", aes(fill = log10(z), 
     color = "low")) + 
     scale_fill_gradientn(name = "z Intensity" , colors = c("darkblue", "blue","red", "darkred"))+ 
     scale_x_log10()+
     scale_y_log10()
```

And here is my plot:[image]

I've tried adding one manually using scale_color_manual() but that doesn't seem to do it. I believe my problem has something to do with how I'm mapping the parameters to aes but I've tried to revise the code all day with no luck. Obviously I'm a baby deer and any help is appreciated in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You added `color` twice in your geoms. You should use `scale_color_manual` instead to choose the colors and `scale_shape_manual`for the shape:

```
ggplot(data = data, aes(x=x, y=y, color=lvl, shape=lvl)) +
  geom_point(data = high,aes(color="high",shape ="high"), size = 2) +
  geom_point(data = mid,aes(color="mid", shape ="mid"),  size = 4, stroke = 1.5) +
  geom_point(data = low, aes(fill = log10(z),color = "low", shape = "low"), size = 4, stroke = 1.5) +
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(18, 21, 2))+
  scale_fill_gradientn(name = "z Intensity" , colors = c("darkblue", "blue","red", "darkred"))+ 
  scale_color_manual(values = c("gray81", "black","black"))+ 
  theme_classic()+
  theme(legend.position="right")+
  scale_x_log10()+
  scale_y_log10()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much, this worked. I was confused about how to layer so your answer helped me see how it's done.